# Angular 2 Route Guard logic

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

Service:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, public af: AngularFireAuth) { }

  canActivate() {
    this.af.authState.subscribe(res => {
      if (res && res.uid) {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      } else {
        // Prevent user from accessing any route other than /login or /register.
      }
    });
    return true;
  }
}
```

Router Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';

import { LoginComponent } from 'app/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from 'app/register/register.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from 'app/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

What the canActivate function does is redirect the user if they are logged in or not.  I have the guard attached to the routes in my router module, but I'm having trouble figuring out the correct logic for the next step:

If the user is not logged in, they should not be able to access any route other than /login or /register.  Of course I could add `this.router.navigate(['/login'])` in the else statement, but then that makes /register non-accessible.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use the AuthGuard for routes, that need to be protected, which in your case seems to be the dashboard only. The `canActivate` reads like: "This given AuthGuard can activate this route, if it returns true." instead of "This route can activate another route." So you could do as follows:

#### Routes

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },  
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

#### AuthGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  private isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(private router: Router, public af: AngularFireAuth) {
    af.authState.subscribe(res => this.isLoggedIn = res && res.uid); 
  }

  canActivate() {
    if (!this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

With this, dashboard won't be accessible and redirect to /login when not logged in. You could have a link from the LoginComponent to the RegisterComponent, so it becomes reachable.

I presume that you have a LoginService? The service could redirect to the dashboard route, when the login was successful.

More information can be found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard